# htaccess rewrite rules to remove multiple subfolders from a URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Due file system sub-directory constraints I will most likely reach I want to separate the `/users` folder into `/users/a/username`, `/users/b/username`, `/users/c/username`, etc.

So the data on the server for a user would be in:
`www.domain.com/users/a/username/`, `www.domain.com/users/b/username`/, etc

I want the URL to be:
`www.domain.com/users/username/`

Optionally to avoid duplicate content a 301 redirect from www.domain.com/users/a/username/ to `www.domain.com/users/username/` would also be good.

Currently I have a rewrite for a single sub-directory (see below) but I'm confused how this can be done efficiently for all of the alphabetical sub-directories.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ users/a/$1 [L,NC]
```

I have checked this site and all seem to hide the first sub-directory e.g. `domain.com/folder1/filename.html` => `domain.com/filename.html` but nothing in more depth.

Comment: How do you get the letter `a` or `b` or ... when you have `domain.com/users/username/` to rewrite ? Is it corresponding to user's first letter ?

Comment: Yes it is I should have made that clearer.

Comment: Some of your comments are missleading, take `Optionally to avoid duplicate content a 301 redirect from www.domain.com/users/a/username/ to www.domain.com/users/username/ would also be good.` seems to be the other direction...

Comment: The URL's I want indexed are without the a-z subfolder. Apologies as my understanding with Rewrite rules are basic.

Comment: How are the username1 subfolders distributed? by first character?

Comment: A full example would be www.domain.com/users/a/anne/ displaying as www.domain.com/users/anne/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower    # this line in your apache file configuration
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/users/[a-z]/([^/\s]+)\s
RewriteRule . /users/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^users/([A-Za-z])([^/]+)/$ /users/${lowercase:$1}/$1$2/ [L]
```

Comment: Your first rule won't redirect for all files within /users/a/username1/ddd, or am I wrong?

Comment: @MrTux You're right but that's not the goal here. When `/users/a/username` is reached, no matter if there is something after, it is redirect to `/users/username`

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if that's what the OP wants ;)

Comment: Thanks and I pretty much understand that, but strangely it is also causing a redirect loop even after removing the other lines in my htaccess

Comment: @MattHirons You're right, i forgot something. Now i tested it and it's working. See my edited code

Comment: Thanks I have just used it and the redirect works but then I get a 404 error. There is nothing else in my htaccess now not even a RewriteBase

Comment: This means you don't have a file like `index.html` or `index.php` in your directories. The rule internally rewrite to `users/LETTER/username/`

Comment: When putting www.domain.com/users/a/username/ in it redirects and the browser states: The requested URL /users/u/username/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Yes that's what i told you. Let me be clearer: if you go to `www.domain.com/users/MattHirons/` it will be internally rewritten to `/users/m/matthirons/`. If you don't have an index directory (like a file called `index.html` or `index.php`) you have the behaviour you described. Tell me where in directories (which file) the rule should rewrite instead ?

Comment: I do have the index.php files. On the server I have /users/m/matthirons/index.php and have added the answer code in the htaccess file in the root. So my objective is to basically hide the /m directory in the URL while serving the /users/m/matthirons/index.php content.

Comment: That's weird because i tested it with `index.php` and the rule worked for each users. Could you look into rewrite logs ?

Comment: This worked perfectly when I tested in another browser and fine in Chrome when I re-started. Thanks again this is very useful and not something I could find elsewhere on here.

Comment: That's my fault, i should have told you to refresh your browser's cache and try again, sorry. You're welcome, glad it helped

Comment: Could this be modified based on the case so if you go to www.domain.com/users/Matt/ it will be internally rewritten to /users/m/Matt/

Comment: Isn't it the opposite of your initial question ?

Comment: No the same as your current answer but to allow for upper and lower case just on the username directory on the server. The LETTER directory will always be lowercase though.

Comment: Right. I edited my answer, you can try it. Don't forget to clear your browser's cache before trying (rules are cached because of 301 redirect) or try with another browser

Comment: Thank you this worked when I moved the RewriteMap line to my httpd.conf file