# Apache htaccess rules involving RewriteMap lowercase - convert to Nginx rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I currently have the following in a .htaccess file which is working fine, but need to convert it to work with nginx:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/users/[a-z]/([^/\s]+)\s
RewriteRule . /users/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^users/([A-Za-z])([^/]+)/$ /users/${lowercase:$1}/$1$2/ [L]
```

I have read up on more general cases of rewrites to lowercase in nginx and recompiled nginx with the --with-http_perl_module option, but cannot get this specific example working.

So far I have the following:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/users/([A-Za-z0-9_-])([^/]+)/$ /users/$1/$1$2/;
        }
}
```

Comment: For more context please see my original question a while ago where the htaccess rules were sorted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353101/htaccess-rewrite-rules-to-remove-multiple-subfolders-from-a-url

Comment: I have sorted this out now by adding the ngx_http_lower_upper_case module to nginx and using the following:
    `location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    lower $lowercase_user_dir "$1";

        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/users/([A-Za-z0-9_-])([^/]+)/$ /users/$lowercase_user_dir/$1$2/;
        }
}`

Comment: You should add that as an answer (and later accept it) as it may help other readers. The question also remains in the unanswered question queue otherwise. Thanks :)